# Property grid with optional members best approach

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, enums, propertygrid

I have a property grid object that requires you to choose an enum, for example, you have:

```
enum XScalingType { ShowAll, Fixed, Sigma }
```

Now, based on this enum selection, we only care about certain parameters.  Namely:

```
ShowAll - requires none
Fixed   - double Minimum, double Maximum
Sigma   - double Sigma
```

This leaves me with the following class

```
class MyPrefs
   XScalingType XScale
   double minimum  //only matters when XScale = Fixed
   double maximum  //only matters when XScale = Fixed
   double Sigma    //only matters when XScale = sigma
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.  My thoughts where, I need to make min\max\sigma all members, and just hide them from the grid if they aren't used.

However, that doesn't seem like common practice.  Is there a more formal way to use these optional parameters based on other enum selections?

I'm wondering if I'm approaching this from the wrong direction completely.

Comment: I'd say that the common practice with property grids is to leave all the parameters on the grid at all times, and simply document the fact that some parameters are ignored if other parameters are set in particular ways.  You may want to name the parameters in a way that gives the user a hint, e.g. "FixedMinimum", "FixedMaximum."

Comment: I've been searching through the standard property grids used by Microsoft, and this seems to be their solution as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach is to create state-aware property accessors like the following:

```
public double? Sigma
{
    get
    {
        if (XScale == XSCalingType.Sigma)
            return _sigma;
        else
            return null;
    }
    set { _sigma = value;}
}
```

then if XScale is anything other than Sigma, the property Sigma will show empty.

Comment: Thanks for the help, nullable properties is definately the best approach.